# Global.asax and handling exceptions that occur in spawned Threads

Tags: asp.net, exception, global-asax

I have an exception handler .
In my asp.net application. 
It’s written in Global.asax. 
In the the Application_Error() method.

It works for Exceptions that happen in the context of pages and classes that are called as a result of a request to the application.
But if I spawn a thread, as a result of a request (or other reason, like an application-based timer), and an Exception in that thread.
It isn’t handled by the Global.asax.
It causes Asp.net’s worker process to kill my application.
Dead.
If I plug into the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException handler, I see the exception that occurs in my Thread, but alas, this is too late. 
And the application still dies.
Dead.
Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exceptions in secondary threads are not reported by the unhandled-exception events

use [SafeThread](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SafeThread.aspx) for your secondary threads

caveat: I am the author of the SafeThread article, and the app-monitoring product CALM